# yacc - use of parenthesis with expression - reduce/shift

Tags: yacc, parentheses

I'm trying to use parenthesis '()' in yacc grammar definition.

this line is working well:

```
x == 1 && y == 0
```

but this line can't be parsed:

```
(x == 1) && (y == 0)
```

when I compiled, I have 1 conflic and at the parsing a error:

**conflicts: 1 shift/reduce**

**syntax error (105;264) before &&**

Here is a part of the syntax I use.

```
%type <node> full_expression signed_expression boolean_term boolean_expression expression term factor
%type <nodeList> dst_list dst
%nonassoc EQ NEQ GE GT LE LT
%left '=' '(' ')' '+' '-' '*' '/' OR AND
%right '?' ':' 

boolean_expression:
boolean_term
  { $$ = $1;}
| '(' boolean_term ')'
  { $$ = $2;}
;

boolean_term:
expression EQ expression
   { $$ = buildAndPrintBinaryOperator ($1, $3, "EqualityComparator"); }
| boolean_term AND boolean_term
   { $$ = buildAndPrintLogicalOperator ($1, $3, "And");}
| boolean_term OR boolean_term
   { $$ = buildAndPrintLogicalOperator ($1, $3, "Or");};

expression:
term
| signed_expression '+' term
  { $$ = buildAndPrintBinaryOperator ($1, $3, "Adder");}
| signed_expression '-' term
  { $$ = buildAndPrintBinaryOperator ($1, $3, "Subtractor");};

term:
factor
| term '*' factor
   { $$ = buildAndPrintBinaryOperator ($1, $3, "Multiplier"); }
| term '/' factor
   { $$ = buildAndPrintBinaryOperator ($1, $3, "Divider");};

factor:
INT
{
  $$ = (node*) malloc (sizeof (node));
  $$->isNumber = 1;
  $$->ref.value = $1;
}
| DOUBLE
{
  $$ = (node*) malloc (sizeof (node));
  $$->isNumber = 1;
  $$->ref.value = $1;
}
;
```

the problem seems to be on the **'(' boolean_term ')'** line. The parser reach this line then: parsing error.

I don't understand what should I do to remove the ambuity and resolve my problem. It seems to work on other exemples ?

any ideas ?

regards

Answer (score 1):

Well, the syntax error is because you're missing a rule to parse a parenthesized expression.  You probably want to add:

```
factor: '(' expression ')'
```

for that.  Its not clear where the shift/reduce conflict is coming from, because there is none in the code you've posted.  Try looking at the y.output file you get from `yacc -v` -- that will tell you which state is involved, and looking at the state in question will tell you which rules are involved.

Comment: And remove the similar rule for `boolean_term`, which is in the wrong place anyway.

Comment: Hi EJP and thanx for your reply, but what do you mean by "remove the similar rule for boolean_term" ?
are you talking about **'(' boolean_term')'** in boolean_expression or about **boolean_term** (definition).
thanx

Answer (score 0):

I finally find my mistake. It was in the grammar itself.
I replace **boolean_term** by **boolean_expression** in case of **AND** and **OR**

```
boolean_expression:
boolean_term
  { $$ = $1;}
| '(' boolean_term ')'
  { $$ = $2;}
;

boolean_term:
expression EQ expression
   { $$ = buildAndPrintBinaryOperator ($1, $3, "EqualityComparator"); }
| boolean_expression AND boolean_expression
   { $$ = buildAndPrintLogicalOperator ($1, $3, "And");}
| boolean_expression OR boolean_expression
   { $$ = buildAndPrintLogicalOperator ($1, $3, "Or");};
```